# How to create report table in sql?

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2005, javafx

I am creating In-patient management system desktop application in
javafx as my mini project of MCA, which has some data about patient admitted in hospital.

I have to save all the records of patient test & test reports in a database.

So, I have created `Test` table with following attributes

```
->(T_ID, P_ID, T_NAME, T_DATE),
```

`Report` table with following attributes

```
->(R_ID, P_ID, P_NAME, T_DATE, REF_BY)
```

So, there are multiple types of Test Report like,

```
eg. CBC_REPORT, LFT_REPORT etc.
```

then how should I create the relationship between this table.

I tried but I am facing problem in user interface for inputing values
in table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something likewise,

Total 4-Database Tables needed.

> Table-1 : Patient
>
> Description : store patient related information....

```
Table-Fields :
        P_ID [ primary key ]
        P_NAME
        REF_BY
```

> Table-2 : Test
>   Description : store test related information....

```
Table-Fields :  
        T_ID [ primary key ]
        T_NAME
        T_DATE
```

> Table-3 : TEST_REPORT   Description : this table is most important
>   which will help us to grab data like, for whom report/test.....

```
Table-Fields :
        TR_ID  [ primary key ]
        P_ID   [ foreign key : Patient(P_ID)]   whose test-report is this...?
        T_ID   [ foreign key : Test(T_ID)]      for what test ?
        R_ID   [ foreign key : Report(R_ID)]    which report ? eg. CBC_REPORT, LFT_REPORT etc.
```

> Table-4 : Report  Description : store unique report name/related
>   information....

```
Table-Fields :
        R_ID  [ primary key ]
        R_NAME [ Report Name ]
        R_DATE
```

> Enter data into table into following sequence,
>
> 1. identify/create patient    From/To : Patient-table
> 2. create test To : Test-table
> 3. identify/create report From/To : Report-table
> 4. insert/create To : TEST_REPORT-table
>
> while needed to grab data then follow this sequence,
>
> 1. refer TEST_REPORT-table
>
>    1.2. based upon T_ID, P_ID, R_ID go ahead...

Best of Luck
Let me know if have any query then.

Comment: Thnax Vishal.. I got your idea till entering data into the table through GUI. But, I need to print each report through Jasper Report. So how can I know  which report is this at GUI level while printing??

Comment: @PrathameshRane while grab data first refer TEST_REPORT, and sorry i am not much familier  with Jasper Report.